# showing div after fadeout second time

Tags: javascript

js code :

```
function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#axx').fadeOut('fast');
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }, 1000)
}
```

css code : (for testing js)

```
#axx{
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 25px;
    background:black;
}
```

html code :

```
<div id="axx" style="position: absolute;">asd</div> //the shown/hidden div

<input type="button" class="button_p_1" onclick="showStuff('axx');"></input> // the button is jsut for testing
```

its working great for the first time, but if i click the button again, the div wont show up, i tried getting the style out of settimeout function still not working.

i'm trying to use it for errors and success messages how can i make it work?

Comment: i need some detail:
1) you tell about "button" wht button?? (maybe post HTML) 
2) var id value?

Comment: hey why not post an example in pastebin or any other such site... Its too vague to answer as we have to reconstruct the whole page. and most of us haven't got enough time for that

Comment: edited, ronnie i'm sorry for that, i was thinking the problem is with the js, as its working great for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `fadeOut` hides the `axx` element by setting its transparency and not by visibility.
Try to `fadeIn` it back.

```
function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#axx').fadeOut('fast');
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        $('#axx').fadeIn();
    }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also with animate():

```
function showStuff(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#axx').animate(
    { visibility: 'visible' }, 500, 'linear');
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }, 1000);
}
```